# Loosing internet connection while connected to specific VPN server?

Tags: network, privacy, vpn, openvpn

I have noticed a strange behaviour earlier today on my VPN on a specific server.

1. When I run a trace route command while connected to VPN (on a specific countries server) my internet will not work for around 10 seconds during the test (I can't access any sites, any downloads get stopped) and then it somehow reconnects and everything is back to normal i.e. it finishes the trace route and I can access websites and download.

   When this happens my VPN still shows connected to the server even though I do not have any internet access. By the way I still do not have access to the internet even with my killswitch being enabled or disabled.
2. Somehow related to the first point. But some servers (like the one above) on my VPN service (a popular well known service) can be buggy, they display the same behaviour as during the disconnect above.

   That is I do not have any internet access (i.e. Google won't load and any downloads stop downloading) but it is still showing me as connected to the VPN service sometimes it will come back other times I might need to connect to another server.

In either case I cannot find any signs of a leak since when I am connected to the VPN all the tests online show no DNS/IP leaks and the weird behaviour is occurring I have 0 access to the internet so I don't know how I could be leaking.

So I basically have a few questions:

- Do I need to be concerned for leaks from using this server? This is my main concern.
- What is causing this strange behaviour?